# SharePoint access to path denied only in production

Tags: development, splistitem, word

I followed [this][1] to convert a SharePoint List Item to word (and then word to PDF). I am using a dotx template file from a Document Library to create a word file and save it in the same doc library. When I deployed this custom solution on test server it worked fine(worked fine on Dev too), but when I move the same solution to Production, I get "Error :Access to the path '\SERVERNAME\sites\SITENAME\DOCLIBNAME\Forms\StaffTemp.dotx' is denied."

Here is how I am copying the file....
string templateFile = "\\SERVERNAME\sites\SITENAME\DOCLIBNAME\Forms\StaffTemp.dotx";

string destinationFile = "\\SERVERNAME\sites\SITENAME\DOCLIBNAME\" + filename + ".docx";

File.Copy(templateFile, destinationFile, true);
File.SetAttributes(destinationFile, FileAttributes.Normal);

Can anyone tell me what I can do to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Please fix your link and formatting.

Comment: This link works without any error in dev and test server. I am getting error only in production. Also I don't see any error in this link.

Comment: I was referring to your original post. The link isn't present.

Comment: I'm sorry. Here is the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2012/02/17/how-to-create-a-document-from-a-template-dotx-dotm-and-attach-to-it-using-open-xml-sdk/